Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value'). I am trying to build a todo app using react js
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value'). I am facing this error and not finding a way to fix it. I am trying to build a todo app using react js. Below is the app.js code...
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [addTodo, setAddTodo] = useState([]);

  console.log(inputValue);
  return (
    <div classNameName="screen-background-color">
      <div className="app-content-background">
        <div className="todo-list-heading">
          <h1>To-Do List</h1>
          <img className="todo-image-styles" src="./images/icon.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-and-btn-styles">
          <input
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={setInputValue((e) => e.target.value)}
            className="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add Your Task"
          />
          <button onClick={setAddTodo(inputValue)} className="add-btn">
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="unchecked-image-and-text">
          <img
            className="unchecked-image"
            src="./images/unchecked.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <h4 className="unchecked-h5-heading">{addTodo}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Just a typo. You want onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}

you're incorrectly setting the onChange handler. The correct syntax is to pass a function that updates the state based on the event. You've currently passed the result of setInputValue((e) => e.target.value) directly to onChange, which is incorrect.
Similarly, in your button component, you're directly calling setAddTodo(inputValue) in the onClick handler, which is also incorrect.


import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleAddTodo = () => {
    if (inputValue.trim() !== "") {
      setTodos([...todos, inputValue]);
      setInputValue(""); // Clear input after adding todo
    }
  };

  console.log(todos);

  return (
    <div className="screen-background-color">
      <div className="app-content-background">
        <div className="todo-list-heading">
          <h1>To-Do List</h1>
          {/* Replace with correct path to your image */}
          <img className="todo-image-styles" src="./images/icon.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="input-and-btn-styles">
          <input
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            className="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add Your Task"
          />
          <button onClick={handleAddTodo} className="add-btn">
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="unchecked-image-and-text">
          <img
            className="unchecked-image"
            src="./images/unchecked.png"
            alt=""
          />
          {/* Display todos */}
          <ul>
            {todos.map((todo, index) => (
              <li key={index} className="unchecked-h5-heading">
                {todo}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;




Your onchange is incorrect, instead of this:
onChange={setInputValue((e) => e.target.value)}

it should be this:
onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
(e) => denotes a function that is being created
